# Tips on resources for moveable components

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, dhtml

I would like to create a user interface like the iGoogle or facebook profiles where the end user can customize the layout. Move components around, resize e t c

Do you have any suggestions on resources/code examples in order to create something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/MakingGoogleIG.aspx

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets - i think it will be good starting point for pure AJAX solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.NET, as you say you are, look into something like [ASP.NET Web Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx) or [dropthings](http://dropthings.omaralzabir.com/). The [codeplex site for dropthings is here](http://www.codeplex.com/dropthings/).

Answer (score 0):

Before making any decision do checkout [extjs](http://www.extjs.com/products/extjs/) Layout Managers from the left navigation.